# Do the Bounty Badges really belong under "Question Badges"?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges, bounties

There are 4 badges related to bounties, and they are listed under the "Question Badges" section:

[image: Bounty Badges]

I understand the reasoning here. Bounties are directly related to questions (in that they are offered on questions); however, they are also directly related to answers (in that they are awarded to answers).

It seems to me like these badges might be better suited under the "Participation Badges" section.

What do you think?

Comment: I see your point, but in the context of the badges, they are more about the question than the answer... offering a bounty on your own **question**, manually awarding a bounty on your own **question**.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The badges are worded this way, but it seems to me that you're not really "awarding a bounty on a question" so much as you are "awarding a bounty *to an answer* on a question."